# Turning on and off background tasks in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, background-task

I'm currently developing an Ionic / Cordova app, and I've a little question about Angular. I've got some states, and I go from a state to an other using $state.go. Each state got his controller, and it's working great.

Now I'm trying to add a GPS tracker (the app is for an orientation game, it allows the game master to follow players) but I don't know how to do it. I need to create a module / service / function / whatever which can be launch from anywhere in any controller, and can be stop using the same way.

I'd like to start this "thread", containing a setInterval function that's refreshing the position, and continue to navigate between states and controllers. But I need to stop it at the end of the game, so I need a way to shut it down.

Can you please help me to do that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can use web workers to achieve it if you want the process to run on its own thread. Kindly check the project below :
https://github.com/mattslocum/ng-webworker
https://github.com/FredrikSandell/angular-workers

Comment: Alright, but is it possible to get the control on the function after controller has changed ? Because it will loose the promise, right ?

Comment: Yes that might be so. But you can use localStorage or sqlite to store the finished work of the webworker along with a flag and you can access the data in any controller. Kindly upvote if you found my answer useful.